# AppCenter won't update io.elementary.Platform(and SDK) Flatpak runtime

Tags: appcenter

This problem has plagued me for the past couple days. I noticed that one day I updated everything from the AppCenter, and it still had 2 Operating System Updates left, so I tried to update them again, it would just go from Starting to Installing, then stop and act like I had never pressed the update button.

I've tried updating from command line, running flatpak repair (and --reinstall-all), flatpak update, none of these helped.

[image: AppCenter Update]

Comment: Adding my two cents to this running Horus: It still happens, thus it in fact has not been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me before, since the os is in beta, you can expect these things.

1. Firstly you can try updating AppCenter trough apt via

   `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`

   And try updating again.
2. If it still refuses to update, you can also upgrade flatpak in terminal!

   `sudo flatpak update`

These should resolve your issue.

Hope I clould help

Answer (score 0):

I see this is for Elementary OS 6 I am testing the exact system as well, and this has already been fixed.